# Not able to read Japanese File Name inside the Spring Controller

Tags: spring

Not able to read the file if the filename contains Japanese Characters inside Spring Controller and it is deployed in tomcat7 server and have the printed the path in print statement shows Quest Mark[enter image description here][1].

Added the URI Encoding="UTF-8" in tomcat server.xml and specified in the catalina.sh file
[enter image description here][2] change also done web.xml file character encoding filter has been set in that still have the same issue.

Note :
But able to read the Japanese Filename  in normal core Java Application it is working.

Comment: There is too little to no actual information only a description. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to write a proper question. For starters include some code (as code not as images or links to images!), configuration etc.

Answer (score 1):

The issue exists with Tomcat7.0.54.
It got fixed in Tomcat7.0.109

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).